# How to show/popup a sheet to display some link info from a WKWebView

Tags: swiftui

This example code displays a list of `items` and navigate to the `DetailView`
where I display the html text in a `WKWebView`. All works well, and
when I click on the link, the linked page is displayed.

What I would like to do is to popup a separate `sheet` or similar, when I click on the link.
So that the linked `page` info is displayed in the sheet and then return to the view when
the sheet is dismissed.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    let itemsModel = [
        MyItem(txt: "item-1", html: "<a href=\"https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/\">link to SwiftUI</a>"),
        MyItem(txt: "item-2", html: "<a href=\"https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui-concepts/\">link to SwiftUI concepts</a>")]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(itemsModel) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(item: item)) {
                    Text(item.txt)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    let item: MyItem
    
    var body: some View {
        HTMLView(html: item.html).padding(30)
    }
}

struct HTMLView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let html: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
      //  uiView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        uiView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> HTMLView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        let parent: HTMLView
        
        init(_ parent: HTMLView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            
            // gives me: ----> url: Optional(about:blank)
            print("\n  url: \(navigationAction.request.url)\n")
            
            guard let url = navigationAction.request.url else {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
                return
            }
            // for testing trying to launch Safari
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }
    
}

struct MyItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var txt: String
    var html: String
}
```

I have tried to add a `Coordinator` class, but I can't see
how I can popup a `.sheet` from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTMLView` can store a handler for when a navigation happens. It could be of type `(URLRequest) -> Void`.

```
struct HTMLView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let html: String
    
    let navigationHandler: (URLRequest) -> Void
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)

        // remember to set the delegate!
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        
    }

    // ...
}
```

The coordinator should call the `navigationHandler` after filtering out undesirable URLs like `about:blank`. It should also `.cancel` the navigation, since you want to show a `sheet` instead.

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    let parent: HTMLView
    
    init(_ parent: HTMLView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        // filters out things like about:blank
        // only keeps the navigation actions that are triggered by clicking a link
        guard let _ = navigationAction.request.url, navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated else { else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        parent.navigationHandler(navigationAction.request)
    }
}
```

In `DetailsView`, you can add a `@State` that stores a `URLRequest?` and display a sheet based on that:

```
extension URLRequest: Identifiable {
    public var id: URL? {
        url
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    let item: MyItem
    
    @State var requestToBeDisplayed: URLRequest?
    
    var body: some View {
        HTMLView(html: item.html) { request in
            // in the navigation handler, assign the URLRequest
            requestToBeDisplayed = request
        }
        .sheet(item: $requestToBeDisplayed) { req in
            Text("\(req.url!)") // or some other view that displays info about the request
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
}
```

Note that I conformed `URLRequest` to `Identifiable` in order to show a `sheet` with it. You can also use a wrapper like this:

```
struct URLRequestWrapper: Identifiable {
    let request: URLRequest
    var id: URL? { request.url }
}
```

in which case you would set `requestToBeDisplayed` to `URLRequestWrapper(request: req)`.

Comment: great answer, works very well, thank you